# How to Drag/Drop objects inside a UIScrollView using a UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I've seen similar questions here, but I haven't seen a solid answer to my question directly.

I have a `UIScrollView` that contains a `UIImageView` object. That view can be zoomed in to view more details on a given photo. When I am zoomed in at any level, panning works as expected. Pinch to zoom works as expected as well.

Now, I want to add another view on top of that image (such as a drawing), but also within the scrollView, so that whenever the scrollView zooms/pans, so does this new drawn view (resizes with zoom)--let's call this drawnView.

Think of this as annotating a picture. I'm viewing an image. I can zoom in/out on the image and pan around to find exactly what I'm looking for. Then, I can draw something on it (no details needed here, this is all working find). But, say I need to move it just a little bit. I want to touch and drag it to a different location.

Whenever I touch to drag the drawnView, I want to be able to drag it around without any delay. I really don't want to use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. I'd rather use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Now, so long as the scrollView is NOT zoomed in at all (zoom factor is 1.0f), the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on my drawnView works just fine. However, as soon as I zoom in at all in the scrollView, the scrollView's `UIPanGestureRecognizer` gets triggered first.

I don't understand why this is the case. My drawnView has `userInterationEnabled = TRUE`, and it's visible, so why doesn't it get the pan gesture first?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
```

If the passed in view is your draw view return NO. Else return yes.